# Getting different user using same IP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm pretty new to SQL Server and need to get different user groups, which are using the same IP address.

Therefore I got

- table table_x -> columns ip_address, userId
- table usergroups -> columns groupId, groupDesc
- table users -> columns userId, groupId

I tried to self join table_x to get different user with the same IP address but unfortunately the outcome is not what I expected.

```
select * 
from table_x x   
join table_x y on (x.ip_address = y.ip_address and x.userId <> y.userId)  
join users u on (x.userId = u.userId)  
join usergroups ug on (ug.groupId = u.groupId)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the expected outcoe and what did you get?

Comment: I can't see your data, so am not posting as an answer. It would be logic to have the last join on u.usergroupId =ug.usergroupId. I really doubt usergroups has a userid worth joining in this context. the join betweem table_x and table_x would also return alot of rows if there are many  identical ip_addresses on each userId

Comment: @t-clausen.dk you are right, thanks! I made a mistake about that. usergroups does not have a column userid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find those ip_addresses with several usergroups:

```
select x.ip_address
from table_x x
  join usergroups ug on x.userId = ug.userId
group by ip_address
having count(distinct groupId) > 1
```

Select the groups with those ip_addresses:

```
select distinct ug.*
from table_x x
  join usergroups ug on x.userId = ug.userId
where x.ip_address in (
    select x.ip_address
    from table_x x
      join usergroups ug on x.userId = ug.userId
    group by ip_address
    having count(distinct groupId) > 1)
```

Comment: As t-clausen.dk mentioned, I made a mistake concerning the columns of usergroups. So I could just use your query, joining users u on (x.userId = u.userId)  and usergroups ug on (ug.groupId = u.groupId). Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

To get all user groups that have multiple users with the same ip you could use the following statement:

```
select distinct ug.* from table_x join users u on (table_x.userId = u.userId) join 
usergroups ug on (ug.userId = u.userId) 
where exists (select 1 from table_x otherUser 
where otherUser.ip_address = table_x.ip_address and otherUser.userId <> tablex.userId)
```